# Can't change method to 'post' in a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As written in the title, i can't change the method of a link_to to :post. Actually, the html generated includes the expected tag `data-method="post"`, but it sends a GET request.

```
<% @playlists.each do |pl| %>
    <%= link_to new_entry_path(:music_id => @music.id, :playlist_id => pl.id), :method => :post  do %>
        <span><%= pl.name %></span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This generates the following html:

```
<a href="/playlist/1/new_entry/3" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">
            <span>dcastro's playlist</span>
</a>
```

Route:

```
match 'playlist/:playlist_id/new_entry/:music_id' => 'entries#create', :as => :new_entry, :via => :post
```

After clicking on the generated link:

```
No route matches [GET] "/playlist/1/new_entry/3"
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: It works if i change the route to `:via => :get` though, but that's not what i need.

Edit: Nevermind, i fixed it. I had a jQuery code to hide/show this menu, and somewhere in it i used event.stopPropagation, which accidentally prevented unobtrusive javascript from changing the hyperlink method to post.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) installed and enabled, which makes non-GET requests from hyperlinks?

If you haven't installed it, even the html5 attribute 'data-method' is properly generated, clicking the link sends a normal GET request.

Comment: Yes i'm sure, i have the jquery-rails 1.0.12 gem installed. Also, i have other hyperlinks in my project which send non-get requests, such as `<%= link_to 'Destroy', playlist, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>`